# Google Puppeteer and Mocha async calls

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, puppeteer

New to JavaScript and trying to understand how to run the following simple test, which loads the google home page, and gets the title. This title is then tested.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
var page_title = "blank";
assert = require("assert");

async function run() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http://www.google.co.uk");
  page_title = await page.title();
  console.log("Page Title: ", page_title)
  await browser.close();
}

run();

describe("Google", function() {
  it("Title contains Google", async function() {
    assert.equal(page_title, "Google");
  });
});
```

The issue is the describe/it block runs before the page_title is obtained. Please could someone advise how I should actually be structuring this?

Comment: If you want to run something before your suite or before each test, then you can use a before hook. [see mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#hooks). Those hooks guarantee that something is run by mocha before or after your suite/test. Next to that, you don't `await`/ use `.then` on the result of  your `run()`, which can also be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks! Adding in the before hook worked:

Comment: describe("Google", function() {
      before(async function() {
        this.timeout(10000);
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto("http://www.google.co.uk");
            page_title = await page.title();
            //console.log("Page Title: ", page_title)
            await browser.close();
          });

          it("Title contains Google", function() {
            assert.equal(page_title, "Google");
          });
        });

Answer (score 0):

You just need read the mocha [documentation](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code). No need to digging deeper, [async code](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) located on the [TOC](https://mochajs.org/#table-of-contents).

mocha offer 3 ways:

- callback

  > Simply invoke the **callback** when your test is **complete**. By adding a callback (usually named **done**) to it().
- promise
- `async` and `await`

So it revised like this with `async` and `await` :

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
var page_title = "blank";
assert = require("assert");

describe("Google", function() {
    // this.timeout(0);
  it("Title contains Google", async ()=> {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();  //headless by default
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("http://www.google.co.uk");
        page_title = await page.title();
        console.log("Page Title: ", page_title);
        assert.equal(page_title, "Google");
        await browser.close()
  });
});
```

My advice is quick reading on every explanation on [TOC](https://mochajs.org/#table-of-contents), and read [brief explanation async and await](https://medium.com/@jamesmarino/the-best-feature-in-javascript-just-came-to-node-js-async-await-ebb7f5d60093)